# Non Clustered Index - One or two index for almost the same need (join between two tables)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a great amount of queries where I make a join between two tables on three columns: col1,col2 and col3. So I created a non clustered index on those three columns in the two tables. But I have the same great amount of queries where I make a join between the two tables on two columns only: col1 and col2.
So what you be more efficient (putting aside the size of the index)?

Create a second non clusted index on col1 and col2 in the two tables or is one of those two indexes enough to handle the work? And if so which one?
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Impossible to answer just like that. It depends on the selectivity of the columns. Multiple indexes means multiple IO operations. The query optimizer will pick whatever appears to cost less. If col1 and col2 have better selectivity and appear first in the 3-column index, the optimizer may pick it. It depends on the table schemas and the actual data statistics

Comment: In any case this is best suited for dba.stackexchange.com, not SO

Comment: Duplicate query in dba.stackexchange.com [Should I use many single field indexes, instead of specific multi column indexes?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12649/should-i-use-many-single-field-indexes-instead-of-specific-multi-column-indexes) with a *very* good answer

Comment: Don't forget that "efficient" needs to take into account the extra processing imposed by indexes on `insert`/`update`/`delete`/`merge` statements. If the tables are frequently written that may make a significant difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, SQL Server indexes, structure, and usage is heavily documented. You should go read up on it.

In the situation you describe, you would want a single index on col1/col2/col3 in that order. That index can be used in both a query with joins on col1/col2/col3 or a query with col1/col2.  That index CANNOT be used in a query that joins on col2/col3 due to how indexes work.

The next thing to consider is the SELECT statement. If you are querying columns other than col1/col2/col3, you will incur key/rid lookups that will hurt performance. You will want to add an INCLUDE section to your index.

Comment: One of the documented things is that just adding individual indexes won't result in *better* performance. I suggest reading Brent Ozar's articles. If col1 and col2 are more selective than col3 and they are specified in the same order on both tables, the query optimizer will be able to use the same index in both cases and run *faster* than if there were individual indexes to read

Answer (score 0):

If you have already an index in columns col1, col2 & col3 and you have queries by col1, col2 & col3 and another queries by col1, col2 it is Ok and the Query Optimizer will use the index in both searches. 
Same question happens if the order is different but the 3 or first 2 fields are used. E.g. col2, col1, col3 or col3, col2, col3.
Different question is if the search uses only by col2, col3 or even only per col2. For these cases you will need to create another index on columns col2, col3.
If you have queries that use only col3 you will need to create another index for col3.